# Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Tags: java, android

how to insert image and textview in scroll view..

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SView"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvNama"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/sound">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvketerangan"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:text="keterangan"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="16sp"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvketerangan"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</ScrollView>
```

this my code.. if i delete imageview,, textview is show and if i delete textview imageview is show...

Comment: Put your other Views inside a `LayoutView` (e.g. `RelativeLayout`) to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggy backing off what GiantTree said, you should change your layout xml to something like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SView"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvNama"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sound">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/tvketerangan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="keterangan"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageview"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:src="@drawable/sa"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tvketerangan"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
  </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thx you... but how the image so that the text below?? im sorry to my english is bad...

Comment: Replace `FrameLayout` with `RelativeLayout`. If you want the Text below the Image, give the `TextView` a property of `android:layout_below="@id/imageview`.

Comment: can you help me?? how to stop sound by press back.. i want to stop my sound being played from when my Activity is paused..i mean stay in my activty..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i mean .. how to Stop sound file when back pressed in Android.. ?

Comment: No idea. That is something for its own question, not a comment on this answer.